# can't replicate submitting a form through a post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post

Trying to recreate a post request submitted by a form on a website, however when i directly recreate the request with the node module request, i get a 302 status code and the body is empty. I will attach pictures of the post request I am trying to recreate and the code I have (I am persisting cookies with a cookie jar and am making the proper requests beforehand to store the login cookies and such). Thanks!

[image: This is the post request I am trying to replicate]

```
const request = requests.defaults({
       jar: true
   })
const fetchGradesData = {
       'f': 'f',
       'javax.faces.ViewState': 'j_id5',
       'f:inside:GradedTab:AssignMPSel': '4',
       'f:inside:GradedTab:j_id_jsp_394614891_10pc8': '03-16-2019',
       'f:inside:GradedTab:j_id_jsp_394614891_12pc8': '06-07-2019',
       'f:_idcl': 'f:inside:j_id_jsp_1774471256_10pc5'
   }
   const fetchGradesHeaders = {
       'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
       "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
       "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
       'Connection': "keep-alive",
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36",
   }

   request.post(
       "https://mybackpack.gulliverschools.org/SeniorApps/studentParent/academic/dailyAssignments/gradeBookGrades.faces", {
           headers: fetchGradesHeaders,
           formData: fetchGradesData
       },
       function (err, response, body) {
           console.log(response.statusCode)
       }
   )
```

Here is the code i am using to send the post request.

Below are the response headers that I am getting and the ones from chrome dev tools:

[image: Response Headers]

```
{ date: 'Mon, 01 Apr 2019 17:29:19 GMT',
  server: 'Apache',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'x-xss-protection': '1;mode=block',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
  'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'self\' mybackpack.gulliverschools.org:444     *.senior-systems.com:444 *.google-analytics.com ; script-src  \'self\' mybackpack.gulliverschools.org:444     *.senior-systems.com:444 seal.godaddy.com \'unsafe-inline\' \'unsafe-eval\' *.google-analytics.com; style-src   \'self\' mybackpack.gulliverschools.org:444     *.senior-systems.com:444 \'unsafe-inline\'; img-src     \'self\' mybackpack.gulliverschools.org:444     *.senior-systems.com:444 data: *.google-analytics.com seal.godaddy.com *.seniormbp.com ; object-src  \'self\' mybackpack.gulliverschools.org:444     *.senior-systems.com:444 *.google-analytics.com *.seniormbp.com \'unsafe-inline\'; child-src   \'self\' mybackpack.gulliverschools.org:444     *.senior-systems.com:444; frame-ancestors \'self\'      *.senior-systems:444 *.goradius.com;',
  p3p: 'CP=\'CAO PSA OUR\'',
  'cache-control': 'no-store',
  expires: 'Mon, 01 Apr 2019 17:27:39 GMT',
  'x-powered-by': 'JSF/1.2',
  'set-cookie': [ 'senior.session.expired=true' ],
  location: 'https://mybackpack.gulliverschools.org/SeniorApps/studentParent/academic/dailyAssignments/gradeBookGrades.faces?convid=20816',
  'content-length': '0',
  'keep-alive': 'timeout=5, max=100',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive' }
```

Comment: Can you show the response headers please?

Comment: @Tabare updated the post with the headers! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302), the **Response code 302** is:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 302 Found redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header. A browser redirects to this page but search engines don't update their links to the resource (in 'SEO-speak', it is said that the 'link-juice' is not sent to the new URL).

So, I would suggest you to take into account this case that happens when the resource is termporary unavailable in that *url*.

One way of doing this could be by asking for the response code and in case it is a 302 repeat the request but to the link in the location response header.

Comment: thanks for the response, however i tried to send the same post request to the location URL however I get the same 302 response and an empty body.

Comment: And does the new request have a response response header of location? (if that's the case then I would try repeating the process until the response code changes)

Comment: So i made a recursive function that essentially calls the same post request to the location header if the status code is 302 (with a 2 second delay) and it has called itself around 50 times already so that unfortunately did not work

Comment: Then I can't tell how to resolve this, please post the solution (in case you find it)